# Mentor and Mentoring

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Would someone who is not a professional but knows a subject (such as automotive repair) in depth and offers advice and hands-on assistance with repair procedures be considered a mentor? Is the act of giving advice in this context mentoring?

Comment: I would say consulting. I always think of professional when I hear mentoring.

Comment: @speedyGonzales On what basis do you suggest 'mentoring' is always professional? To me, mentoring could well be done by a friend or acquaintance, and be informal and free of charge. 'Consulting' sounds more professional to me, and also more likely to be paid for, especially as 'Consultant' normally refers to a paid professional.

Comment: Why would you think not? Mentor: adviser - preceptor - monitor - counselor - tutor. What has a professional to do with *that*?

Answer (score 2):

*Mentoring* refers to the passing on of knowledge and expertise over a long period.

The *mentor* might be a professional, but they also might not. Likewise the relationship between the mentor and the *protégé* might be within a professional context, but again it might not.

The skill the training is in might not even be one that is ever professional; people often mentor in hobbies, sports and other avocations that don't have a professional structure.

Comment: True. However, this is GR!

Comment: OK, so as I understand it now, for a person to call themselves a "mentor" or be "mentoring" someone, the person is doing more than giving advise on an occasion or two.  It's over a long period of time to the same person.  Using automotive repair, a person who instructs someone on a repair procedure or walks them through it on the phone or chat cannot be considered a mentor if it's not a recurring instruction or guidance?